# Efficient placement of haircards?

Tags: particles

I have a game character which I want to add fur via haircards. Now, I've already made the haircard with texture and everything, but how can I apply hundreds of cards onto my model without having to do one at a time all the time.

I tried using the particle system but it wouldn't have the correct rotation and it placed them in a very bad way. Is there a hidden tool or feature in blender that I can use to place the hair cards on?

It's a big creature and it's going to require a lot of haircards to look right, and placing one by one could very well take weeks...

So is there a way of simplifying the process?

Comment: You could initially use a particle system to place them roughly over the mesh, apply it, then manually tweak what parts aren't good enough

Comment: With particles you can change the rotation so that most of them sit right, then straighten out the rest by hand.